# How can I trigger on URL change in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I trigger a function when the URL changes? I try something like:

```
$(windows.location).change(function(){
   //execute code
});
```

So my URL is something like `http://www.mysite.com/index.html#/page/1`. How can I execute jQuery or JavaScript code when the URL becomes something like `http://www.mysite.com/index.html#/page/2`?

Comment: There are already many questions like yours.. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+hash+changed

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That would be a `hashchange` event, so I'd suggest:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    // do something...
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wzeTY/).

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
I think this error appear because my URL are smt like index.php#/page/1

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `on()` is available from version 1.7+, versions older than that should use `delegate()`, but without further information I can't say.

Answer (score 4):

Try the `hashchange` event, which is built exactly for this - http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

```
var current_href = location.href;
setInterval(function(){
    if(current_href !== location.href){
        // if changed Do ...
        current_href = location.href;
    }else{
        // Do ...
    }
},500);
```

This worked for me ^^

$(window).on('hashchange') // not firing

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

```
$(function(){
    $.address.strict(false);

    $.address.internalChange(function(e) {
        // do something here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To Detect URL change only for pop use

window.onpopstate = function (event) {
//`enter code here`
}