# jquery function doesn't work on changing url

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I'm working on something I dubbed hashtag-links.
With it, I'm trying to make deep linking possible in a one page website where all of it's content is hidden and everything hangs together with javascript, jquery and php (Wordpress).

With `window.location.hash` I can read part of the url and with a switch statement, I can launch certain functions that load the right previously hidden `div`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    switch(hash) {
        case "#faq":
            showOverlay('faq', 'menu-up');
            break;
        case "#contact":
            showOverlay('contact-submenu', 'menu-up');
            break;
        case "#reserveren":
            showOverlay('reserveren-submenu', 'menu-up');
            break;
        case "#reserverenjanenl":
            Reserveren('NL');
            break;
        case "#reserverenjaneen":
            Reserveren('EN');
            break;
        case "#reserverenurbnl":
            ReserverenURB('NL')
            break;
        case "#reserverenurben":
            ReserverenURB('EN');
            break;
        case "#reserveringsvraag":
            showOverlay('reserveringsvraag', 'menu-up');
            break;
        case "#groepsreservering":
            showOverlay('groepsreservering', 'menu-up');
            break;
    }
});
```

As you can see, I'm using a `document` `ready` function. This works OK if you navigate to a certain part of the website with a hashtag link from an email and even from a link on an other part of the website.
The problem is, it doesn't work if you're already on the website and you change the hashtag link. In chrome the one time the page reloads and function runs and the other time it just doesn't.
In Firefox and Safari it doesn't do that at all.

It tried `$(window).load(function() {});` and `$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){});` ([based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349907/how-can-i-trigger-on-url-change-in-jquery)) but to no avail.

Try it yourself here:
http://www.thejaneantwerp.com/#contact
Then try changing the hash in the url to #reserveren

Anybody got a solution?

Comment: You can put a click listener on all links and check the hash at that time.

Comment: I see your code in www.thejaneantwerp.com and it works with my answer. Congratulations :) Please, mark it as correct answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, put your code into a function and call it in all events you need (in this case document ready and hashchange):

```
function switchHash() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    switch(hash) {
        case "#faq":
            showOverlay('faq', 'menu-up');
            break;
        case "#contact":
            showOverlay('contact-submenu', 'menu-up');
            break;
        case "#reserveren":
            showOverlay('reserveren-submenu', 'menu-up');
            break;
        case "#reserverenjanenl":
            Reserveren('NL');
            break;
        case "#reserverenjaneen":
            Reserveren('EN');
            break;
        case "#reserverenurbnl":
            ReserverenURB('NL')
            break;
        case "#reserverenurben":
            ReserverenURB('EN');
            break;
        case "#reserveringsvraag":
            showOverlay('reserveringsvraag', 'menu-up');
            break;
        case "#groepsreservering":
            showOverlay('groepsreservering', 'menu-up');
            break;
    }
  }

$(document).ready(switchHash);
$(window).on('hashchange', switchHash);
```

Comment: This seems to work although it doesn't hide the old div, but I think I can fix that. Will mark as answer when I do.

Comment: Hide the old div is another task, and very simply, but the problem you reffer in the question is solved, I see it in your website :) It's a pleasure to assist you. See you later!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're a victim of your own success here. Anchors (the hash value) are specifically designed to work by not reloading the entire page, just skipping to where the anchor is. So if you change the has value in the URL, it will not reload the page, just jump to that anchor.

But, in your case, because you're not using them as anchors, but as a switch statement content, it does nothing when you change the anchor. Your JQuery function doesn't run again because the page doesn't reload - $(document).ready runs exactly once when the page is finished loading. No reload - no rerun of the function.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Makes sense yes. Thanks for the explanation.